# Power needed to generate for heating strip - Nichrome strip element

Tags: heat

I have a nichrome strip, about 8 mm in width - 0.25 mm in thickness - 1 m in length.
I tried working around various formulas but can't seem to get a definite answer regarding how much power should i generate for 270°F heat roughly.

The strip is to be used in an impulse sealer. Therefore the main usage will be sealing plastic bags at most. It will be working at room temperature, so I would say there are not a lot of external factors.

Comment: It depends entirely what you're heating, and how much heat it loses to its environment.

Comment: A heater in a fast flowing stream of water is going to take a *lot* more power to reach 270F than the same heater wrapped in a ball of (heat resistant) insulation.  That's why you can't find a simple answer.

Comment: You would probably be better asking this question on the physics side. it's highly dependent on what your heating, not on the wire at all.

Comment: Otherwise if you give the mass and type of material your heating, there's probably a few people here me included that could do the calculation or show you how it's done.

Comment: Thank you for the kind inputs and my apologies for the incomplete question. The strip is to be used in an impulse sealer. Therefore the main usage will be sealing plastic bags at most. It will be working at room temperature so i would say there are not alot of external factors. Seeking advices..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

8mm x 0.25mm = 2mm<sup>2</sup>, which is "roughly" the same resistance as 14AWG. According to the calculator at [Jacobs Online](https://www.jacobs-online.biz/nichrome/NichromeCalc.html), 1m of 14g Nichrome 60 produces "roughly" 270°F from 22.3W (3.5V x 6.37A).

But heat is not temperature. The wattage above applies when cutting expanded polystyrene foam. In still air the wire might get less cooling and need less power. But flat strip has more surface area than round wire, so it may get more cooling and need more power - unless wound in a helix when it may need less power. But if attached to something that acts as a heat sink it will need more power, etc.

Without knowing the parameters of the thermal environment a definitive answer isn't possible, but hopefully this "rough" estimate is close enough to provide a starting point.